# Ubuntu 14.04 will not show network manager icon

Tags: 14.04, wireless, icons

My wireless information is here at http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8379981/ .
I have tried stopping the Network Manager and deleting the .state file associated with it, then restarting the process. No methods I have been able to find online have helped me so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate here:
[My Network Notification icon not showing Ubuntu Kylin 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772425/my-network-notification-icon-not-showing-ubuntu-kylin-14-04/772614#772614)
I would suggest one of the answers that were given to me, try to enter Ubuntu's recovery mode and follow the other steps suggested.

Or you could download your package iso to a USB stick and take update the Network Manager from the USB stick.

The only thing that worked for me though was to update Ubuntu from the USB stick, from 14.04 to 16.04.

Comment: If a question is a duplicate of another question, you can report (flag) it as duplicate not sharing the link as an answer

Comment: I am new to this, I do not have privileges to mark as duplicate.