# My Network Notification icon not showing Ubuntu Kylin 14.04

Tags: network-manager, icons, notification

I know this is a question asked a lot,but I have tried almost every solution out there and the network icon is still not showing. 
I am using Ubuntu Kylin 14.04.

I tried to access nm-applet but it said that it was not installed.

The problem with the other solutions was that they required update or installing from terminal, but I do not have any internet connection available so any of these solutions do not work for me.

I also tried this solution proposed

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
$ sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
$ sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start
```

I tried to go to the file NetworkManager and change the status to true.

Can anyone suggest me some other solution? Or should I just reinstall Ubuntu again?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the network indicator ?  tried reinstalling network manager ?

Comment: @Serg How do I do that? Does it requires internet? If not how?

Comment: yes, it does require internet, you can use wired internet. And for indicator there's couple of ways. 1) `sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-network` 2) `sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete` . For reinstalling network manager , try this:  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager` or see if any of [these](http://askubuntu.com/q/422928/295286) work for you

Comment: @Serg I cannot use wired internet

Comment: Well, this is the best I can suggest. Maybe others will have better ideas

Comment: Did you check aswers [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/771627)? You can download newer `network-manager` package on different machine and pass it via usb (as in my answer) or use Ubuntu's built-in recovery mode (as in Jit's answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of failed attempts, I tried the solution @tamkderplar suggested to use Ubuntu's recover mode. Unfortunately it did not work.

So I tried my last resource, I used the update from USB stick. And since I was there I also updated my Ubuntu Kylin from 14.04 to 16.04.

Finally the network icon showed up.

I do not know why none of the solutions worked for me though.